# Convert json with duplicated keys to gson

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I'm trying to get both the Ys in this JSON structure using gson and kotlin

```
{
"y": {
       "x":"value",
       "y":"value"
     }
}
```

The first y I got it using this code:

```
@Expose
@SerializesName("y")
val y:String?
```

but the second y I couldn’t reach it.

Comment: The first y is a map, not a string

Comment: that's because the first y is an object

Comment: @Zoe it's a string :( , but still if you could introduce me the solution in case if it is a map

Comment: @a_local_nobody yeah so how can I reach the second y?

Comment: No, the first y is not a string. It's an object like a_local_nobody said, which is represented as a map in Java. The _second_ y is a string, and it's stored as a key in the map of the first y. While I have no idea how you're meant to expand this (because I don't know or use gson), in a raw map equivalent, you get the value of the second y with `json["y"]["y"]`

Answer (score 0):

The first Y is object while the second one is string those are the models written in Java just copy paste them in android studio and it will convert them to Kotlin

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("y")
@Expose
private Y y;

public Y getY() {
return y;
}

public void setY(Y y) {
this.y = y;
}

}
```

.............................................

```
public class Y {

@SerializedName("x")
@Expose
private String x;
@SerializedName("y")
@Expose
private String y;

public String getX() {
return x;
}

public void setX(String x) {
this.x = x;
}

public String getY() {
return y;
}

public void setY(String y) {
this.y = y;
}

}
```

There are plugins in android studio that can convert all Json to Pojo classes you should try them (like: JsonToKotlinClass)

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
data class ObjectY(
    @SerializedName("x") val stringX: String,
    @SerializedName("y") val stringY: String,

    )

data class ResponseY(
    @SerializedName("y") val y: ObjectY,
    )
```